# Excel like format/sheet in an asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel

I have a requirement to have an html table (or anything that implement that functionality) look like a excel sheet (means user could able to type and copy paste text to that table) into my .net application. Please give me some ideas to implement this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some 3rd-party components which do exactly what you describe... is a commercial component an option for you ?

Comment: i don't consider this as a question, please do some research before.

Comment: @Ali: one should respect every one posting here. This is a place to share knowledge not to dominate someone. Don't reply if you don't have the answer. The person asking question here may not be an expert, thats why asking for help.

Comment: I didn't disrespect him! He is asking for a complete solution and this isn't what stackoverflow was made for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery to solve this problem.

Follow the given steps in order to implement this functionality -

1. Create a table with heading and one additional row.
2. Place textboxes inside the blank row.
3. Place an "Add" button at the top/bottom of table. (or wherever you like).
4. Use JQuery to add new row dynamically to this table.

I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks you Irfan for your help. Really appreciated. But I am not familiar with jQuery. I was concerned whether it is possible with asp:Table control. That is to make that table editable when user clicking on that. I just need some idea whether it is possible or not so that I can reserch more on that. But I could solve this by using GridView control :)

Thanks again